# $r (t) = (\cos (wt), \sin (wt), t^2 )$ Find an equation for the tangent line at $t = 4\pi/w$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$r (t) = (\cos (wt), \sin (wt), t^2 )$ Find an equation for the tangent line at $t = 4\pi/w$

I have the answer in front of me, but nothing I try seems to be able to come up with it, I am looking for some starting steps. Thanks.

Comment: What's something that you have tried?  Also, it's better to at least copy the formulaic content of your question to the body of your question.

Comment: I am kind of lost on the conceptual level, I don't know exactly what they are looking for when they say "tangent line at." I have just taken the partials, and tried plugging in 4pi/w at different times.

Comment: what's the answer ? Try $r_0+t\dot r_0$ where, after you find $\dot r=dr/dt$, both $r$  and $\dot r$ are evaluated at $4\pi/w$ to get $r_0$ and $\dot r_0$. For example, $r(t)=(\cos(wt),..)$, $\dot r(t)=(-w\sin(wt),..)$, $r_0=(1,..)$, $\dot r_0=(0,..)$, tangent line $r(t)=(1,..)+t(0,..)$.